# Sending ID input from submit to controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view which I need to take a user input, and send it to a controller action. I have tried several things but what references I have found online have not seemed to be working for me. I have an input in a form, and I have the controller and action name listed, however it does not seem to be passing the value from the users input. In fact, unless I hardcode the value into the controllers parameters, when I get to the page I just get error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'Namespace.Controllers.TerminalReceiptsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

Parameter name: parameters

Otherwise, when hard coded into the controller params, it works just fine.

Below is some code.

View import portion:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TerminalReceipts"))
 {

  <div>
    <input type="text" name="ID" />
     <input type="submit" value="Find Receipts">
  </div>

   string Id = Request.Form["ID"];
}
```

View table portion:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" style="overflow-y:scroll">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="terminalReceipts">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Local Transaction Time</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Receipt</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var item in Model.TransactionsTests)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.TransactionTime</td>
                    @*<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocalTransactionTime)</td>*@
                    <td>@item.Amount</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("View Receipt", "Details", new { Key = 1 }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" }) <br /></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller action:

```
        // GET: TerminalReceipts
    public ActionResult Index(int id )
    {
         var model = TRBL.GetTransactionTestsData(id);
        //var model = new TerminalReceiptsVM();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Where in my code (specifically the view import portion) am I going wrong?

Comment: In which code you are passing value for `id` from view to controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try bellow:

Remove `string Id = Request.Form["ID"];` from your view and use `button` instead of input for button control:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TerminalReceipts"))
{
   <div>
     <input type="text" name="ID" />
     <button type="submit">Find Receipt</button>
   </div>
}
```

In controller's action, mark the action method as `POST` to differ it from `GET` method.

```
// GET: TerminalReceipts
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id )
{
     var model = TRBL.GetTransactionTestsData(id);
    //var model = new TerminalReceiptsVM();

    return View(model);
}
```

Please note that, if you do not mark an action method as `POST`, by default it will be considered `GET`. So the problem you are facing is you are calling the method on `GET` request where you need to provide the value to the parameter as query string.

PS: For your scenario, I am recommending to use two `action` methods for `Index` view. One for `GET` where it displays the form, the second `POST` action method to get the data from the form on submission.

Comment: Ok. I will try this. However, the issue is, I am using the same Index action to return the view to the table below. I am not sure how I can handle this, I would like the table to be blank before the user enters the ID, then when the button is clicked, have the table be willed with the data. How can I accomplish this using two Index actions?

Comment: Okay, I have done what you said and made a second Action with HttpGet for the initial load. This works fine now. However, when the HttpPost Index action, I get this error when entering in an id and clicking submit. The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in Controllers.TerminalReceiptsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Oh, I see. Parameter name in HttpPost action must be same exact declaration as the input name. This works!!! Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `string Id = Request.Form["ID"];` and `<input type="text" name="ID" />` to `string Id = Request.Form["id"];` and `<input type="text" name="id" />`   mapping it with the lower case perimeter name in the controller.